# How to properly add files to .gitignore and remove them from the repository?

Tags: git

I am working on a large project whose `.gitignore` wasn't complete. I added many entries to the `.gitignore`, and I would like to `git rm` **all the files that were previously committed but are now in .gitignore**. There are **tons of** files that need to be `git rm`ed, so doing it one by one is close to impossible.

Before asking this question, I have done some research on it already.

The first method is to recursively `git rm` all files and then `git add` all files with **the updated `.gitignore`**.

```
$ git rm -r --cached /path/to/project
$ git add /path/to/project
```

The second method is to `git ls-files` **all files that need to be ignored but are still tracked** and then rely on `bash` shell command to do all the work.

```
$ git ls-files --exclude-standard -ci -z | xargs -0 git rm --cached
```

Both methods above lead to **the same** changes staged to be committed as shown below. However, there are some unexpected files in the list.

```
Changes to be committed:
        deleted: previously                   (A)
        deleted: committed
        deleted: files
        deleted: that
        deleted: should
        deleted: be
        deleted: removed

        deleted: others                       (B)
        deleted: not
        deleted: even
        deleted: ignored
```

As is indicated by the file names, I only want `A` to appear in the list, not `B`. I've double checked my `.gitignore` and made sure that `B` are not in it.

Essentially, what I don't understand is, **what could possibly cause `B` to be there?**

Comment: `git ls-files --exclude-standard -ci -z | xargs -0 git rm --cached` appears to work as expected (at least, it does for me testing a random repo, only deleting committed files which are ignored - a normal scenario btw). Do you have a file in (A) named `*` for example? I think you need to show some real file names. Also, the contents of the `.gitignore` would help as there's probably an overly-greedy pattern in it. (Please edit the question to address comments :)).

Comment: Have you verified a path in B with `git check-ignore -v <path>` to make sure that there isn't another ignore pattern that is being matched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is pointed out by the comments, the reason `B` are there is that your `.gitignore` has a greedy pattern in it. You can use `check-ignore` to debug your `.gitignore`.

```
git ls-files --exclude-standard -i -z | xargs -0 git check-ignore -v --no-index
```

Note that, in your case, **--no-index** option needs to be set because your `A` and `B` **were** `git add`ed, but now, although maybe unintentionally for `B`, **are** in `.gitignore`.